# Django REST Framework custom permission class not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my attempt to troubleshoot an issue, I'm trying to force my custom permission class to return False and it's not.  I'm still able to perform a successful GET and POST request via the DateListViewSet class below. I can't figure out why my custom permission class (IsUser) below isn't working  Below is my custom permission class, view class and serializer.  Please assist

Custom Permission Class

```
class IsUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permissions(self, request, view):
        return False
```

Mixin and View Class

```
class DateListMixin(object):

    serializer_class = SimpleDateSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsUser)



class DateListViewSet(DateListMixin, generics.BulkModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):

        num = self.kwargs['rm']
        num2 = self.kwargs['id']
        r1 = Room.objects.get(pk=num)


        s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=num2)
        u = self.request.user.pk
        usr = User.objects.get(pk=u)

        if(s1.user.username == usr.username):
            queryset = r1.transactiondatetime_set.all()
            return queryset
        else: raise Http404("User does not exist")
```

Serializer class

```
class SimpleDateSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin, ModelSerializer, serializers.Serializer):
    start_dt = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    class Meta(object):
        model = TransactionDateTime
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
        fields = ('pk', 'start_dt', 'room')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45793581/6839331

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom permission in viewset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793581/how-to-add-custom-permission-in-viewset)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out it. I should have typed permission instead of permissions

Comment: where should you write permission instead of permissions?

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, the custom exception class's method should read:

```def has_permission(self, request, view):``` (not ```has_permissions(...)```).