# How to add custom permission in viewset

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

How to add custom permission in viewset in django rest framework other than the default permission while creating a module?
I have a permission "fix_an_appointment". In the below viewset, how to include this permission? Those who have this permission has only able to create.

My views.py file:

```
class settingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
    queryset = Setting.objects.all()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: People coming here for answer: Look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970970/django-rest-framework-permission-classes-of-viewset-method?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

I can't use a decorator like: `@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated, )` in extra actions within ViewSet

To use different permissions in actions, instead, put it into the `@action()` as a parameter.

```py
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
       ...
```

[drf doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Answer (score 1):

by docs [custom-permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), list of view actions [actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)
*my_permissions.py*

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class FixPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    fix_an_appointment
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated :
            if view.action == 'retrieve':
                return request.user.has_perms('fix_list_perm')
            if view.action == 'retrieve':
                return request.user.has_perms('fix_an_appointment')
        return False
```

in views.py

```
from my_permissions import FixPermission


class settingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
    queryset = Setting.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (FixPermission,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to add custom permission seperate for each action add, edit, delete and update. How to do that?

Comment: edited answer with actions view, more details of all action in link

Comment: @BearBrown perhaps you meant to define the `permission_classes` attribute as a list? Like: `permission_classes = [FixPermission]` ? If not this throws following error: `TypeError: 'BasePermissionMetaclass' object is not iterable`

Comment: @railomaya probably you miss comma `,`. `(1, )` is a tuple `(1)` is an int

Answer (score 0):

simply create a [custom permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

```
class FixAnAppointmentPermssion(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True or False
```

then the in your view set class use your custom permission

```
class settingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
    queryset = Setting.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (FixAnAppointmentPermssion,)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set permission for each functions like create, retrive, update, delete(add,edit,delete and update)

```
from my_permissions import FixPermission

class FixAnAppointmentPermssion(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
       return True or False

class YourViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
queryset = Your.objects.all()

@permission_classes(FixAnAppointmentPermssion,)
def create(request, format=None):
  content = {
           'status': 'request was permitted'
  }
return Response(content)

@permission_classes(FixAnAppointmentPermssion,)
def retrive(request, format=None):
  content = {
           'status': 'request was permitted'
  }
return Response(content)
```

Comment: This does not work when we are using `ViewSet`. I doubt if this will work even when you are using class based views (CBV). I haven't been able to find a direct mention of using `@permission_classes` decorator in conjunction with CBV or ViewSet in the DRF documentation. I personally tested this with ViewSet and it just ignores the permission classes. However setting the `permission_classes` attribute of the class that takes a list of custom permission classes does work.